# How to find out what Windows Media Player version I have?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, version

Microsoft appears to be removing about boxes for its operating system apps.

How do you get the version of Windows Media Player?

I can't find it reported on any of the windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open WMP, right click on the top bar (Next to the Album playing...), then Help - About Windows Media Player (I have Windows 7 and WMP12)

Also listed here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190990:

> To determine the version of Windows Media Player, start Windows Media
>   Player, click **About** on the **Help** menu in and then note the version
>   number below the Copyright notice. If the **Help** menu is not displayed,
>   press **ALT + H**, on your keyboard and then click **About**.

Comment: That's what I thought but I was running a media player window that didn't have this look - I didn't start it from the start menu. When running media player from the start menu, the larger window was shown and I could find the help about. I rarely use this program so I can't remember what it does.

Comment: Anytime my friend!