# Which version of Windows Media Player is installed on my Windows 8 PC?

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out what Windows Media Player version I have?](https://superuser.com/questions/120985/how-to-find-out-what-windows-media-player-version-i-have)

When I start my Windows Madia Player I can't find any information about the Version. Where to get such an information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the version of Windows Media Player, start Windows Media Player, click About on the Help menu in and then note the version number below the Copyright notice.

If the Help menu is not displayed, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, on your keyboard and then click About.

Comment: [I found this info too](http://superuser.com/questions/120985/how-to-find-out-what-windows-media-player-version-i-have), but it doesn't seem to work on Windows 8. I can't find the Help menu, even not by pressing `Alt`+`H`.

Comment: Tap and release Alt. From the menu that appears, click Help, then "About Windows Media Player". On Windows Enterprise RTM I'm seeing version 12.0.9200.16420. Also, Alt-H works fine for me - start Windows Media Player, then with it in the foreground, hold down the left Alt key while tapping H once.

Comment: Right click on the media player icon on your desktop and select properties. This should tell you what version you have.

Comment: @MarkAllen That worked. Only `Alt` though, not `Alt`+`H`.

Comment: @Ace-Legend Thank you, it works. I have 12.0.9200.16420 )

Answer (score 3):

You can also go to the Windows Media Player folder located in Program Files, right click the file `wmplayer.exe`, go to `Details` tab and check `Product version`.

[image]